# check if two object list have the same property

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, salesforce-lightning

I have two objects lists which they have different fields in them.I want to check if two fields dont have same value in them in javascript.
 my example is  list one

```
0:Client_Issue_Reference__c:null
  End__c:"2018-03-06T23:00:00.000Z"
  Id:"a0Q2F000000oRyBUAU"
  Resource_Full_Name__c:"test user"
  Start__c:"2018-03-06T15:00:00.000Z"
```

and my second list is

```
0:Id:"0050W000006r0xnQAA"
  IsActive:true
  Name:"test user"
```

I wanna see if Resource_Full_Name__c != Name 
currently I have

```
for (var i = 0; i < listOne.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < listTwo.length; j++) {
     if (listOne[i].Name != listTwo[j].Resource_Full_Name__c) {
          buildingObjectAllUser = {}
          sobjectType: "testObject";
          buildingObjectAllUser.Id = listOne[i].Id;
          buildingObjectAllUser.Start__c = "2018-03-06T23:00:00.000Z";
          buildingObjectAllUser.End__c = "2018-03-06T23:00:00.000Z";
          buildingObjectAllUser.Name = "No Hours";
          buildingObjectAllUser.Resource_Full_Name__c = listOne[i].Name;
          listThree.push(buildingObjectAllUser);
        }
      }
    }
```

the problem with this one is taking to much time, its really slow

Comment: `sobjectType: "testObject";` ????

Comment: If the order of `listThree` is not important, you can create subarrays and use Promises to execute in parallel the searching process.

Comment: Turn list two into an object keyed off `Name`. That way those look ups will be `O(1)`

Comment: @MattBurland that solution is good but when you put all together it turns `O(n)`

Comment: @Ele: Yes, I know. That's why I said *the look up* is `O(1)`

Comment: @MattBurland right right! `:)`

Comment: can u point me to an example of it @MattBurland

Comment: @AB74574 Please specify, why do you use a for-loop within a for-loop ? Do you need to compare each element with all other elements from the 2nd list ? Don't you just need to compare `listA[i].Resource_Full_Name_c` with `listB[i].Name` ?

Comment: @PascalLamers I want to see if they are not equal

Answer (score 0):

this should be faster

```
let list1 = [{Client_Issue_Reference__c:null,
  End__c:"2018-03-06T23:00:00.000Z",
  Id:"a0Q2F000000oRyBUAU",
  Resource_Full_Name__c:"test user",
  Start__c:"2018-03-06T15:00:00.000Z"}]

let list2 = [{Id:"0050W000006r0xnQAA",
  IsActive:true,
  Name:"test user"}]


list1.map(obj => {
  let checker = list2.find(obj2 => obj2.Name === obj.Resource_Full_Name__c)
  if (!checker) {
    let buildingObjectAllUser = {}
    sobjectType: "testObject"
    buildingObjectAllUser.Id = listOne[i].Id
    buildingObjectAllUser.Start__c = "2018-03-06T23:00:00.000Z"
    buildingObjectAllUser.End__c = "2018-03-06T23:00:00.000Z"
    buildingObjectAllUser.Name = "No Hours"
    buildingObjectAllUser.Resource_Full_Name__c = listOne[i].Name
    listThree.push(buildingObjectAllUser)
    return buildingObjectAllUser
  }
})
```